# Can we give runat server to jQueryUI autocomplete field

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to use jQueryUI autocomplete.The Autocomplete is completely rendered using jQuery. However I want to be able to access the "project" input control in my .cs code as well. Is it possible?

I tried putting in runat server but the _renderItem throws an error during page load in that case. The autocomplete and rendering works fine without the runat="server attribute.

```
<input id="project" runat="server" />

.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    }
```

Any pointers would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add name attribute to your input element and get value on server side by Request.Form[name]

aspx page:

```
<input type="text" id="project" name="project" value='<%= ViewBag["project"]  %>'>
```

server side getting value

```
var project = Request.Form["project"];
```

passing value back to the client

```
ViewBag["project"] = project;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we assign values using this? and its available on post backs and first time loads as well?